# excel conditional formatting with msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

i wanted to select a range and put a conditional formatting such as cell values should be in between 0 and 5, if not then not format, but instead display message box asking to enter value between 0 and 5. can you show how to do it if this is possible at all? thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of Conditional Formatting and Data Validation. In Excel 2003, look into the Data/Validation dialog to set the criteria, input message, and error message. Then apply the formatting with "Format/Conditional Formatting" as I suspect you already know how.

PS. Sorry I am lost with the Excel 2007+ ribbon interface. Menus above are given where Excel 2003 has them.